# The base class includes the field 'CrystalReportViewer', but its type is not compatible with the type of control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5 and it doesn't work on my system in an asp.net project in visual studio 2013.

**Error:**
*The base class includes the field 'CrystalReportViewer', but its type (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer).*

My web.config:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <!--<add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>-->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

My aspx page's top:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

The assembly version of Crystal reports:

```
13.0.22.2668
```

The assembly version installed on pc:

```
13.0.2000.0
```

How do I solve this?

And when I make the version number same i.e. 13.0.2000.0 in all places then it throw this error on runtime?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: You must use from this link:
https://adilmca.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/visual-studio-2012-crystal-report-not-working-on-windows-server-2012-0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-bobj-is-undefined/

Comment: link is not opening for me can you post here